# Python/Scikit-Learn - Can't handle mix of multiclass and continuous

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to fit an SGDRegressor to my data and then check the accuracy. The fitting works fine, but then the predictions are not in the same datatype(?) as the original target data, and I get the error

```
ValueError: Can't handle mix of multiclass and continuous
```

When calling `print "Accuracy:", ms.accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)`.

The data looks like this (just 200 thousand + rows):

```
Product_id/Date/product_group1/Price/Net price/Purchase price/Hour/Quantity/product_group2
0   107 12/31/2012  10  300 236 220 10  1   108
```

The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics as ms

msk = np.random.rand(len(beers)) < 0.8

train = beers[msk]
test = beers[~msk]

X = train [['Price', 'Net price', 'Purchase price','Hour','Product_id','product_group2']]
y = train[['Quantity']]
y = y.as_matrix().ravel()

X_test = test [['Price', 'Net price', 'Purchase price','Hour','Product_id','product_group2']]
y_test = test[['Quantity']]
y_test = y_test.as_matrix().ravel()

clf = SGDRegressor(n_iter=2000)
clf.fit(X, y)
predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
print "Accuracy:", ms.accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)
```

What should I do differently? Thank you!

Comment: You may consider converting the continuous values to discrete by rounding the continuous values to nearest integer using the round function. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015181/accuracy-score-valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-binary-and-continuous) for similar question answered by [*natbusa*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511809/natbusa)

Comment: Dutse is right. Or you can use `y_preds = y_preds > 0.5` to change to discrete. Here  you can set your own threshold.

Comment: @SharkDeng you are wrong, as is the previous comment; the root cause of the issue is as already pointed out in the answers below (the linked answer was also wrong)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Accuracy is a classification metric.  You can't use it with a regression.  See [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) for info on the various metrics.

Comment: So how exactly can I predict with my model? I mean, if `clf.predict(X_test)` gives me different output than the original, how am I supposed to even use it? This has got me puzzled.

Comment: @lte__: In general you cannot expect to get exactly correct results from a regression model.  What you hope for is that your predictions are overall close to the real values.  To decide if they are close enough, you need to use a different evaluation metric (one of the regression metrics).  See the documentation link I provided, which explains many metrics.

Answer (score 32):

Accuracy score is only for classification problems. For regression problems you can use: R2 Score, MSE (Mean Squared Error), RMSE (Root Mean Squared Error).