# Why not use mean squared error for classification problems?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, cross-entropy, mean-square-error

I am trying to solve a simple binary classification problem using LSTM. I am trying to figure out the correct loss function for the network. The issue is, when I use the binary cross-entropy as loss function, the loss value for training and testing is relatively high as compared to using the mean squared error (MSE) function.

Upon research, I came across justifications that binary cross-entropy should be used for classification problems and MSE for the regression problem. However, in my case, I am getting better accuracies and lesser loss value with MSE for binary classification.

I am not sure how to justify these obtained results. Why not use mean squared error for classification problems?

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515202/why-is-the-cross-entropy-method-preferred-over-mean-squared-error-in-what-cases) might have the answer you're looking for! The 'accuracy' reported by the network during training isn't necessarily all it sounds like; a [roc curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve) will give you a better idea of how a binary classification network is actually performing. :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'd like to share my understanding of the MSE and binary cross-entropy functions.

In the case of classification, we take the `argmax` of the probability of each training instance.

Now, consider an example of a binary classifier where model predicts the probability as `[0.49, 0.51]`. In this case, the model will return `1` as the prediction.

Now, assume that the actual label is also `1`.

In such a case, if MSE is used, it will return `0` as a loss value, whereas the binary cross-entropy will return some "tangible" value. 
And, if somehow with all data samples, the trained model predicts a similar type of probability, then binary cross-entropy effectively return a big accumulative loss value, whereas MSE will return a `0`.

According to the MSE, it's a perfect model, but, actually, it's not that good model, that's why we should not use MSE for classification.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. The MSE loss is not zero. Squared error means you literally _square the error_. Thus, if your model predicted 0.51 and the label was 1, the squared error would be (1-0.51)^2. Averaging this across the examples in the dataset gives the MSE.

Comment: True, I wrongly interpreted MSE as an accuracy and evaluated loss on the basis of accuracy only and thats the reason I set the loss will be 0 in such a case. I will update my response, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to show it using an example.
Assume a 6 class classification problem.

Assume, 
     True probabilities = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

**Case 1:**
Predicted probabilities = [0.2, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16]

**Case 2:**
Predicted probabilities = [0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0, 0, 0]

The MSE in the Case1 and Case 2 is **0.128** and **0.1033** respectively.

Although, Case 1 is correctly predicting class 1 for the instance, the loss in Case 1 is higher than the loss in Case 2.

Comment: But when you calculate the cross-entropy on both cases, isn't that you will find out Case 2 still has the lower loss even though it is predicting wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but your point is moot. Both MSE and CE will be higher for Case 1: [see here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l-bS1O1hFv2M0UorC-rc8vjm5EeFv23e?usp=sharing). Case 1 is basically just a bunch of noise in all categories with 0.2 being barely above the noise.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is right there in your question. Value of binary cross entropy loss is higher than rmse loss.

### Case 1 (Large Error):

Lets say your model predicted 1e-7 and the actual label is 1.

Binary Cross Entropy loss will be -log(1e-7) = **16.11**.

Root mean square error will be (1-1e-7)^2 = **0.99**.

### Case 2 (Small Error)

Lets say your model predicted 0.94 and the actual label is 1.

Binary Cross Entropy loss will be -log(0.94) = **0.06**.

Root mean square error will be (1-1e-7)^2 = **0.06**.

In Case 1 when prediction is far off from reality, BCELoss has larger value compared to RMSE. When you have large value of loss you'll have large value of gradients, thus optimizer will take a larger step in direction opposite to gradient. Which will result in relatively more reduction in loss.

Answer (score 2):

Though @nerd21 gives a good example for "MSE as loss function is bad for 6-class classification", it's not the same for binary classification.

Let's just consider binary classification. Label is `[1, 0]`, one prediction is `h1=[p, 1-p]`, another prediction is `h2=[q, 1-q]`, thus their's MSEs are:

```
L1 = 2*(1-p)^2, L2 = 2*(1-q)^2
```

Assuming h1 is mis-classifcation, i.e. `p<1-p`, thus `0<p<0.5`
Assuming h2 is correct-classification, i.e. `q>1-q`, thus `0.5<q<1`
Then `L1-L2=2(p-q)(p+q-2) > 0` is for sure:
`p < q` is for sure;
`q + q < 1 + 0.5 < 1.5`, thus `p + q - 2 < -0.5 < 0`;
thus `L1-L2>0`, i.e. `L1 > L2`

This mean for binary classfication with MSE as loss function, mis-classification will definitely with larger loss that correct-classification.