# LightGBM- Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, lightgbm

I am facing a trouble when I use lightgbm to conduct grid search.

```html
lgb_classifer = lgb.LGBMRegressor(random_state=12)

grid_lgb = {
    'learning_rate': [0.01,0.05],
    'num_iterations': [5,10,20]}

gbm_lgb = GridSearchCV(estimator =lgb_classifer, param_grid =grid_lgb, scoring = 'recall', cv=3)

---> gbm_lgb.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets
```

Both `X_train` AND `y_train` is `array`.`y_train` is binary label.

Comment: What are types of features in the dataset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accuracy Score : ValueError: Can't Handle mix of binary and continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015181/accuracy-score-valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-binary-and-continuous)

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi it didn't have an error when I run any other models like LR,DT,and RF.

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi features includes numerical and categorical data(do one hot).

Answer (score 2):

Ah, i needed a second look. But if it not a duplicate of the issue linked in comments, then the problem can be that you define and train a **regression** model (lgb.LGBMRegressor), while your variable names as well as the chosen metric suggest a classification problem. Try to change the model to `lgb.LGBMClassifier`