# XGBoost produces non-binary predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

After training my model with XGBoost, I tried to test the model but the predictions are some sorts of floating point numbers which cause error when I want to get performacne measures. This is the code:

```
import xgboost as xgb
import sklearn.metrics as mt 

xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:linear', colsample_bytree = 0.3, learning_rate = 0.1,
            max_depth = 5, alpha = 10, n_estimators = 10)
xg_reg.fit(X_train,Y_train)
y_pred = xg_reg.predict(X_test)
mt.f1_score(Y_test, y_pred)
```

And this is the error:

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting.
```

This had never happened when I used other boosting models such as AdaBoost or CatBoost. Should I consider a threshold and assign +1 to those above the threshold, and -1 to those below the threshold? Any kind of advice is appreciated.

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Comment: @desertnaut, yeah, quite helpful! I should replace the regression model with a classifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are in a binary classification setting, as you clearly imply, the issue is that you should **not** use `XGBRegressor`, which is for *regression* problems and not for classification ones; from the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor) (empasis added):

> class `xgboost.XGBRegressor`
>
> Implementation of the scikit-learn API for XGBoost **regression**

You should use [`XGBClassifier`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier) instead.

For more details, see own answer in [Accuracy Score ValueError: Can't Handle mix of binary and continuous target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015181/accuracy-score-valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-binary-and-continuous-target/54458777#54458777) (caution because practically all other answers there, including the accepted & highly upvoted one, are essentially wrong); it is about a practically identical issue with scikit-learn, but the same arguments hold for your case as well.