# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I wrote the following code to learn the score in the machine learning methods. but I get the following error. what would be the reason??

```
veri = pd.read_csv("deneme2.csv")

veri = veri.drop(['id'], axis=1)

y = veri[['Rating']]
x = veri.drop(['Rating','Genres'], axis=1)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)


DTR = DecisionTreeRegressor()
DTR.fit(X_train,y_train)
ytahmin = DTR.predict(x)
DTR.fit(veri[['Reviews','Size','Installs','Type','Price','Content Rating','Category_c']],veri.Rating)
basari_DTR = DTR.score(X_test,y_test)
#print("DecisionTreeRegressor: Yüzde",basari_DTR*100," oranında:" )
a = np.array([159,19000000.0,10000,0,0.0,0,0]).reshape(1, -1)
predict_DTR = DTR.predict(a)
print(f1_score(y_train, y_test, average='macro'))
```

> Error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6271, 3089]

Comment: is the len(x) nd len(y) same for your input??

y = veri[['Rating']]

x = veri.drop(['Rating','Genres'], axis=1)

please mention @ which line you got the error

Comment: `ytahmin = DTR.predict(x)` doesnt has any meaning. You try to predict on all you'r data when you should only predict on training set (X_train) or validation set (X_test)

Comment: @BikiranDas Yes. Both are same input. (len(x)=9360 and len(y)=9360). I think x = veri.drop(['Rating','Genres'], axis=1) give error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least **two** issues with your code.

The first error you report

```
print(f1_score(y_train, y_test, average='macro')) 
Error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6271, 3089]
```

is due to your `y_train` and `y_test` having different lengths, as already pointed out in the other answer.

But this is not the main issue here, because, even if you change `y_train` to `y_pred`, as suggested, you get a new error:

```
print(f1_score(y_pred, y_test, average='macro')) 
Error: continuous is not supported
```

This is simply because you are in a *regression* setting, while the f1 score is a *classification* metric and, as such, it does not work with continuous predictions.

In other words, f1 score is **inappropriate** for your (regression) problem, hence the errror.

Check the [list of metrics available in scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics), where you can confirm that f1 score is used only in classification, and pick up another metric suitable for regression problems.

For a more detailed exposition about what happens when choosing inappropriate metrics in scikit-learn, see [Accuracy Score ValueError: Can't Handle mix of binary and continuous target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015181/accuracy-score-valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-binary-and-continuous-target)

Answer (score 1):

`f1_score` needs to take true `y` from test and the one you predicted on test set, hence last lines should be:

```
DTR = DecisionTreeRegressor()
DTR.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = DTR.predict(X_test)
print(f1_score(y_pred, y_test, average='macro'))
```

You shouldn't call `fit` twice and the shape of your predictions has to be of the same length as test, see some sklearn basic tutorials for more info.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested. but this time I get this error.
Error: continuous is not supported

Comment: That's because f1 score is **inappropriate** for regression problems - see own answer