# Error ValueError: continuous is not supported when tried to use cross_val_score and Linear Regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have used load_boston dataset from sklearn and Linear Regression.
The code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, KFold,cross_val_score,cross_validate
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Loading the dataset
x = load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(x.data, columns = x.feature_names)
df["MEDV"] = x.target
X = df.drop("MEDV",1)   #Feature Matrix
y = df["MEDV"]          #Target Variable
df.head()

linear = LinearRegression()
X_train,X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state = 11)
linear.fit(X_train,y_train)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=11, shuffle=True)
scores = cross_val_score(estimator= linear,cv=kfold, X=X, y = y, )# if scoring= "accuracy": error
```

#>ValueError: continuous is not supported

```
print(f"Mean Accuracy: {scores.mean():.2%} and standard deviation: {scores.std():.2%}")
```

If I use `scoring= "accuracy"` in the cross_val_score, it rises a error:

```
ValueError: continuous is not supported
```

What is happening?

Comment: Accuracy is a classification metric, and it is just meaningless in regression settings, hence the error; see similar situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015181/accuracy-score-valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-binary-and-continuous-target

Comment: Your problem is also regression, and not classification

Comment: You are using `LinearRegression()` in your code. I'm not sure how you can say you are doing classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accuracy does not work here since it is a metric aimed at *classification* problems. Namely it is:

- Number of correct predictions `/` Total number of predictions

By not setting it it works fine, since it defaults to the underlying estimator's scoring, which is the `R^2` score for a [`LinearRegression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score), which is a scoring you should be looking at for a regression problem.

You can have a look at the different scoring types supported in `sklearn` and for what problems they are appropriate:

- [Metrics and scoring: quantifying the quality of predictions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)