# Why can't sklearn MLPClassifier predict xor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

In theory, an MLP with a single hidden layer with just 3 neurons is enough to predict xor correctly. It could sometimes fail to converge properly, but 4 neurons are a safe bet.

Here's an [example](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=relu&regularization=L1&batchSize=10&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.01&regularizationRate=0.001&noise=0&networkShape=4&seed=0.22559&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false)

I've tried to reproduce this using sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier:

```
from sklearn import neural_network
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
import numpy as np


x_train = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (10000, 2))
tmp = x_train > 0
y_train = 2 * (tmp[:, 0] ^ tmp[:, 1]) - 1

model = neural_network.MLPClassifier(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(3,), n_iter_no_change=100,
    learning_rate_init=0.01, max_iter=1000
).fit(x_train, y_train)

x_test = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (1000, 2))
tmp = x_test > 0
y_test = 2 * (tmp[:, 0] ^ tmp[:, 1]) - 1

prediction = model.predict(x_test)
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
print(f'recall: {recall_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
print(f'precision: {precision_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
```

I only get around 0.75 accuracy, while the tensorflow playground model is perfect, any idea what makes the difference?

Tried also using tensorflow:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential(layers=[
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy)

x_train = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (10000, 2))
tmp = x_train > 0
y_train = (tmp[:, 0] ^ tmp[:, 1])

model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train)

x_test = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (1000, 2))
tmp = x_test > 0
y_test = (tmp[:, 0] ^ tmp[:, 1])

prediction = model.predict(x_test) > 0.5
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
print(f'recall: {recall_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
print(f'precision: {precision_score(y_pred=prediction, y_true=y_test)}')
```

With this model I get similar results to the scikit-learn model... So it's not just a scikit-learn issue - am I missing some important hyper-parameter?

**Edit**

Ok, changed the loss to mean squared error instead of cross-entropy, and now I get with the tensorflow example 0.92 accuracy. I guess that's the problem with the MLPClassifier?

Comment: 1) you cannot change the loss at will - the loss is dictated by the problem itself; MSE is for regression problems and CE for classification ones. 2) With MSE (i.e. regression setting) [accuracy is meaningless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse/48788577#48788577) (same for all classification metrics, i.e precision, recall etc).

Comment: @desertnaut You're right that CE is associated with classification while MSE with regression, which is why I've used CE in the first place. But since I take a threshold over the result, I do have a classifier at the end anyway, and thus all these metrics still apply regardless of the loss. Apparently MSE does better here for some reason I can not understand, even though it is a classification problem.

Comment: This may or may not be a good idea; see last part of own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015181/accuracy-score-valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-binary-and-continuous-target/54458777#54458777) and the comment therein.

Comment: @desertnaut right, since the data is symmetric, this is the special case which Andre Ng shows in the beginning of his argument, where linear regression does quite well.

Comment: @desertnaut Actually looking at the playground code: https://github.com/tensorflow/playground/tree/master/src (nn and playground are the relevant ones) - it seems they're using MSE for the classification loss, with tanh activation on the output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the learning rate and/or maximum iterations seems to make the sklearn version work.  Probably different solvers need different values for these, and it's not clear to me what the tf playground is using.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an answer as I stumbled on the same problem. For a research project (to study convergence as the XOR solution is found), I'd implemented my network in Numpy (where I'd written the algebra and gradients myself), but in deploying the same solution with sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier, I'd had little luck with solving XOR using many of the default hyperparameters. But when using the model exactly as I'd implemented it in Numpy, I had no problems with the MLPClassifier.

So, here are the hyperparameter specs that I found led to convergence in my simple XOR problem:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

# XOR data
X = np.array([[0,0],
              [1,0],
              [0,1],
              [1,1]])
y = np.array([
    [-1],
    [1],
    [1],
    [-1]
])

model = MLPClassifier(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(3),
    activation='logistic',#I'm not using relu activation, I'm using the logistic sigmoid
    learning_rate_init=1,
    learning_rate='constant',
    max_iter=100000,#I want to ensure convergence
    n_iter_no_change=1000,#I want to ensure convergence
    tol=1e-6,#shrinking the tol makes false early termination less likely
    batch_size='auto',
    verbose=True,
    #random_state=42,#Want to see convergence for a variety of random seeds, commenting random_state out
    solver='sgd',#Default is 'adam' which I see often not converging
).fit(X,y.reshape(len(y)))
```

Now for your larger XOR simulated dataset, here I make some modifications to your hyperparameters:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

x_train = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (10000, 2))
tmp = x_train > 0
y_train = 2 * (tmp[:, 0] ^ tmp[:, 1]) - 1


model = MLPClassifier(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(3), 
    max_iter=1000000,#More training epochs
    n_iter_no_change=10000,#Since convergence highly desired, raising n_iter_no_change, I have time to watch this train
    learning_rate_init=.01,
    tol=1e-6,#Lowered tol some, to prevent detecting convergence too early and terminating
    solver='sgd',#Default is 'adam' which I see often not converging
    verbose=True,#Can follow convergence at the console, and monitor things
    learning_rate='constant',
    activation='logistic',# I'm using logistic
    alpha=0,#Regularization term, I don't feel I need it here
    batch_size=len(y_train),#Your data isn't so large, let's use all of it at once
    #random_state=42
).fit(x_train, y_train)

# Test out your model
X = np.array([[-.75,-.75],
              [.75,-.75],
              [-.75,.75],
              [.75,.75]])
model.predict(X)

# array([-1,  1,  1, -1])
# Seems to have learned the XOR logic

(model.predict(x_train)==y_train).mean()
# 0.93
# Training with lower tol to lengthen training, accuracy can continue to improve significantly
```

So, to get the most out of the SKLearn classes, you may need to do some experimenting with hyperparameters, but in general the algorithms do work. You have a lot of flexibility to tune models until they're suitable for your data.