# Predict features/result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

In my dataset, there are statistics of every match played by a basketball team during a season (points scored, three-point...). what I want is to predict whether it will win (i.e. 1 or 0) with statistics such as how many points and threes in the next game it will play.

I have defined my variable **y** as the game result in my dataset (0 or 1),
The variable I define as `x_data` is the directory where the team's statistics are kept.

```
y = data.Result.values
x_data = data.drop(["Result"],axis='columns')
```

I first normalize the data and split it as train/test.

```
# Normalization
x = (x_data - np.min(x_data))/(np.max(x_data) - np.min(x_data)).values
# train test split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=42)

x_train = x_train.T
x_test = x_test.T
y_train = y_train.T
y_test = y_test.T
```

and then I try to guess

```
mlr = LinearRegression()
mlr.fit(x_train.T,y_train.T)
mlr.predict(x_test.T)
print("mlr test accuracy: {}".format(mlr.score(x_test.T,y_test.T)))
```

The result I get is just probability. What I want to achieve is to find an answer to the question of whether the team will win or not in the next match.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: The result you get from linear regression is *not* probability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015181/accuracy-score-valueerror-cant-handle-mix-of-binary-and-continuous-target

Comment: If you want a binary decision, this is classification, not regression, so using linear regression makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are talking about is the last print line I see with `mlr test accuracy`?

Because that is just the test performance of your linear model.

To have a proper prediction you need to assign the result of `predict` to a variable.

```py
y_test_hat = model.predict(x_test.T)
```

which will be an array of proper game predictions of your input data.

Last but not least, **I highly suggest to change your regression model to a more suitable classification one** (logistic regression, svm, etc), as your outcome is just a binary output (either the player wins or not).

Comment: thanks for answer. actually, when I do what you say, I can see the results, but I don't understand anything because I normalization the data. sorry it might be a bit silly, but I don't know how to convert to original data from normalization in python.

Comment: Just normalize the input ``x`` used for as training input, it's meaningless to normalize already binary targets. As per the prediction , what you see is just a real number. The closer to 1, the closer to victory, and viceversa. However, these are NOT probabilities, it's just the outcome of a regression on binary values!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your normalization should be done separately for `train` and `test` set. At the present you are leaking your training parameters to your test set. So you need to correct that.

Second, transpose of transpose is the same matrix. e.g. `X.T.T = X`

**Thirdly**, since this looks like a classification problem (either win or lose), `LogisticRegression` is  what you want (instead of `LinearRegression`)

Comment: thanks for answer. actually i know i will use logistic regression but what i want is to be able to see statistics as well. I want to see statistics such as how many points or how many threes the team has scored.

Comment: for that you need to do exploratory analysis of the dataset.